# Laravel 5.2 manyToMany relation with 3 pivot columns issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem with connecting database models in Laravel.

```
Tables: users, companies, company_details
```

Now, I want to connect them, like, each user can have multiple companies, and every company has its company_details.

```
users: user_id, user_username...  

companies: company_id, company_....  

company_details: company_detail_id, ..., company_detail_company_id

[Pivot table] = company_user: id, user_id, company_id
```

My User.php Model looks like this:

```
public function companies()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company');
}
```

How can I get the values from company_details table?

Answer (score 0):

Does your Company Model have a details() method?

Comment: Yes:

`public function companyDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\CompanyDetails', 'company_detail_company_id');
    }`

@pebbo

Comment: You can help from this answer about pivot tables and query

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336145/laravel-how-to-use-multiple-pivot-table-relationships?answertab=votes#tab-top