# laravel 5.2 one pivot with many relations (belongstomany/polymorphic)?

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism, pivot, has-and-belongs-to-many

he guys.
i need your help.

i have three questions about logic and best practice in laravel/eloquent/relation.

*first scenario*

i have four models/tables.

```
1.) model: Ticket | db: tickets
2.) model: Status | db: status
3.) model: Comment | db: comments
4.) model: User | db: users
and
1.) one pivottable between Ticket and Status (status_ticket)
```

logicproblem:

```
1.) one ticket can have many status. (belongstomany/belongstomany)
2.) each status can have one comment (hasone/belongsto) and one user (hasone/belongsto) but only in combination with ticket (pivot:status_ticket).
```

my idea is to give the pivot table two addional cols (withPivot('user_id','comment_id'))

*) first question:
**how can i realize that construct?**

*second scenario*
**the second question is the same as the first one but in these scenario how can i access "comment" not with hasone/belongsto rather with polymorphic-relation??**

my db:

```
comments
    id - integer
    message - string

status
    id - integer
    name - string

tickets
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    name - string
```

*third question*
**what is the best way for naming the pivottable?**

```
1.) 
status_ticket
    id - integer
    comment_id - integer
    status_id - integer
    ticket_id - integer
    user_id - integer

2.)
comment_status_ticket_user
    id - integer
    comment_id - integer
    status_id - integer
    ticket_id - integer
    user_id - integer
```

Answer (score 1):

**my solution:**

i created a model for the pivottable. 
in the pivottablemodel i created a relation with morphOne (comment). 
info: the user_id is now in the comments db.

**DB** (pivot between status and ticket):
    status_ticket

```
id - integer
status_id - integer
ticket_id - integer
```

**DB:**
    comments

```
id - integer
message - string
user_id - integer
commentable_id - integer
commentable_type - string
```

**MODEL:** 
    TicketStatus

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TicketStatus extends Model {

protected $table = 'status_ticket';
public $timestamps = true;

    public function comment() {     
        return $this->morphOne('App\Comment', 'commentable');
    }

}
```

stackoverflow:
[How to use multiple pivot table relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336145/laravel-how-to-use-multiple-pivot-table-relationships?answertab=votes#tab-top)