# Structuring Laravel Controllers

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I have

```
users
    id
    username

companies
    id

areas
    id

area_company
    id
    area_id      
    company_id

area_company_user
    id
    area_company_id      
    user_id

company_user
    id
    company_id
    user_id

area_user
    id
    area_id
    user_id
```

where

- one `user` has 0 to many `areas` AND one `area` can have 0 to many `users`
- one `area` can have 0 to many `companies` AND one `company` can have 0 to many `areas`
- one `company` can have 0 to many `users` AND one `user` can have 0 to many `companies`
- one `area_company` can have 1 to many `users` AND one `user` can have 0 to many `area_company`
- `area_company_user` has attributes specific to that kind of `user`

Also, I'm structuring the routes in the following manner

1. `/users` - all existing users
2. `/areas` - all existing areas
3. `/companies` - all existing companies
4. `/areas/{area}/companies` - all existing companies in a specific area
5. `/users/{user}/companies` - all existing companies from a specific user
6. `/companies/{company}/areas` - all existing areas the company is in
7. `/areas/{area}/companies/{company}/users` - all existing users from a company that exists in a specific area

For 1., 2. and 3. I'm creating controllers that follow the next pattern

- `AreaController` with [methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller) index(), create(), store(), show(), edit(), update() and destroy()

```
GET /areas, index() method,
GET /areas/create, create() method,
POST /areas, store() method,
GET /areas/{area}, show() method,
GET /areas/{area}/edit, edit() method,
PUT/PATCH /areas/{area}, update() method,
DELETE /areas/{area}, destroy() method.
```

There's now basically two cases left from that route list

- **Case 1**: 4., 5. and 6.
- **Case 2**: 7.

My question is, should I create new controllers for each case since I'd like to perform various actions in each? If yes, that'd mean, respectively

- **Case 1**: `AreaCompanyController`, `UserCompanyController` and `CompanyAreaController`
- **Case 2**: `AreaCompanyUserController`

*Note*: [this was a helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23340900/5675325) but didn't exactly address my concern.

Comment: Nothing problematic there with your convention and controller naming (i.e. `AreaCompanyUserController `). I like it how it looks: it is easy readable and understandable. Regarding search mentioned, you can have separated SearchController where you can have various method programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see there is already something called *nested resource* in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-nested-resources) which can cover your cases 4,5,6. In docs there is `PhotoCommentController` which you've described that you're using it (question case 1).
For question case 2 you can for example make [model for pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) and have it that way for route and controller. For example `AreaCompanyUserController` if I understand well, you have here `area_company` pivot table with association of user. So many users can be part of same `area_company` association.
You can circumvent Area and Company models use with use of AreaCompany model that would be the pivot model. Knowing id of that pivot model you can easily get associating area, company and users.

```
class AreaCompany extends Pivot
{
    /** code here */
}
```

Having this, you can name your resource route `/area-companies` and `/area-companies/{$areaCompany}/users` to avoid triple nesting.
I presume any of these decisions have own consequences like subdirectory planning for controllers, form request files, providers, sometimes even route files.
Probably heard and read for thousand times, but important is to stick with consistent way of it. Consider what could be lesser technical debt in some potential upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

In order to simplify the debugging and maintenance process of the project it's better to define the controller for each case in case if anything goes wrong it's easy to debug and solve the problem so you will be having

```
AreaController , UserController , CompanyController
```

Comment: Sure that was implied in 1., 2. and 3. Are you saying I should just stick with these? If yes, how'd you sugest to deal with the other two cases?

Comment: yes stick with that  it is real help in debugging in big projects, and in the other two cases you can include functionalities in one of the base controller  eg for a /users/{user}/companies means to deal with users but who are in the company so its Usercontroller or if functions are too independent just create UserCompanyController

Comment: Right, that's what I was also thinking of. What about Case 2?

Comment: as how it sounds, you need all users so means it's in Usercontroller with parameters company and area

Comment: thing is they'll have attributes specific to that kind of user